# How do I correctly define and interpolate this variable into my find command?

Tags: bash, find, variable-substitution

I  wrote a Bash script, `mscript.sh` for managing my music files, a part of it creates a list of such files.

```
all_exts=" -iname \"*.webm\" -o -iname \"*.mkv\" "
#all_exts=' -iname "*.webm" -o -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" ' 
#The line below works fine
#find "${HOME}/pCloudDrive/SocialSciences/Arabic/al_aghani" -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M \( -iname "*.webm" -o -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" \)|\
find "${HOME}/pCloudDrive/SocialSciences/Arabic/al_aghani" -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M \( "$all_exts" \)|\
awk -v FS="/" '{print $8}' > "${HOME}/pCloudDrive/SocialSciences/Arabic/al_aghani/list"
#it does not work with single quotes either
```

I get the following output,
`find: paths must precede expression:  -iname "*.webm" -o -iname "*.mkv" '`
When I run the script without trying to interpolate `all_exts` to my find command the script work fine. How might I correctly expand `all_exts`?
P.S. This script is simple just for the sake of isolating the problem. I really need to interpolate `all_exts` into the find command because I have many find commands doing this job in many different directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because—since you are quoting the variable, as you should—it is passed aa single string to `find`. You can see this with `set -x`:

```
$ all_exts=" -iname \"*.webm\" -o -iname \"*.mkv\" "
$ set -x
$ find .  "$all_exts" > /dev/null 
+ find . ' -iname "*.webm" -o -iname "*.mkv" '
```

Unfortunately, you can't just not quote it. First because [that can be dangerous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222) so it's best not to make a habit out of it, and second because it wouldn't work here anyway since if you don't quote the expression, the shell will split it and pass it to `find` as separate, quoted strings:

```
$ find .  $all_exts
+ find . -iname '"*.webm"' -o -iname '"*.mkv"'
```

So that would look for files named `"foo.webm"`, where the quotes are part of the file name. The Right Way® of passing such arguments to commands as a variable is to use an array and pass the quoted array to `find`:

```
$ all_exts=( '-iname' '*.webm' '-o' '-iname' '*.mkv' )
$ find . \( "${all_exts[@]}" \)
+ find . '(' -iname '*.webm' -o -iname '*.mkv' ')'
./foo.webm
```